# Good backup/archiving software?

Tags: backup, optical-media

I want to archive several folders and delete them from my HD. What are good software to archive those files, to test the dvds every few months for corruption. Track other dvds that have a copy of said corrupted file(s), etc.

Some folders require encryption, i can provide encryption via truecrypt or other software. There are folders i would like to backup but not delete (it is NOT need to be a diff). What is a good piece of software to use? I am using windows. It would be nice to have a cross platform solution but i am looking for the best solution.

Searching is a plus. Finding dupes and ignoring them is a plus. (we have files hundreds of MB and enough to be a few gigs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For home use, there are tons, [Cobian Backup](http://www.educ.umu.se/~cobian/cobianbackup.htm) is okay, and then there are always the online based ones such as [Mozy](http://www.mozy.com) and [Carbonite](http://www.carbonite.com/).

If you just want to "archive" them to DVD's or something, then any good old burning software would suffice, as for testing them, I would just pop the DVD in and try to read a few files off of it.

You might consider external hard drives as well.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [Cobian Backup](http://www.educ.umu.se/~cobian/cobianbackup.htm) to pretty good success on my 3 Windows machines. It has a ton of built-in features, including encryption, compression, and remote/FTP backups. The scheduler is pretty detailed as well, and can start jobs that were missed if the computer or network was down.

Answer (score 1):

ZenOK [Online Backup](http://onlinebackup.zenok.com/) does the job for me, for personal use I safed my photos, music and documents against a hard drive crash, fire, flood and other threat